# Square Issue in C

Tags: c, windows

Okay so I swear this code should work, but obviously it doesn't. I am attempting to create a Snake game in C, however my Stage isn't displaying correctly. I am attempting to make it so the stage has no characters displaying inside, but only around the perimeter, can anyone assist me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* boolean functions */
#define TRUE 1;
#define FALSE 0;

/* board */
const int length = 20;
const int height = 20;

/* Global Variables */
int x, y, foodX, foodY;
int gameEnd;
int score;

/* movement */
typedef enum {STOP = 0, UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT} movement;
movement move;

/* Game Setup */
void Game()
{
gameEnd = FALSE;
move = STOP;
y = height / 2;
x = length / 2;
foodX = rand() % length;
foodY = rand() % height;
score = 0;
}

/* What is displayed on screen */
void Display()
{
system("cls");
int i;

for( i = 0; i < length + 2; i++)
    printf("#\n");

for( i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        if( j == 0 )
            printf("#");

            printf(" ");

        if( j == length - 1)
            printf("#\n");
    }

}

 for( i = 0; i < length + 2; i++)
    printf("#\n");



}


void Input()
{

}

void Logic()
{

}

int main(void)
{
Game();
while (!gameEnd)
{
    Display();
    Input();
    Logic();
    Sleep(10);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what your current outcome is vs how you want it to be?

Comment: Please don't tag C questions as C++.

Comment: Do not use homebrew boolean constants. C has a built-in boolean type and appropriate constants. (Also review your `#define`s, you have a bad bug there)

Comment: @AlanStokes I apologize, I just figured someone with knowledge in both C and C++ may be able to assist me. Won't happen again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First avoid to make semicolon after the #define, you will get compilation error when you try to pass your constant TRUE to a function.

To have correct display, you should remove the "\n" from printf of first and last for loop of the function Display. And Add printf("\n") just after the for loop. It should be:

```
void Display()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    system("cls");

    for( i = 0; i < length + 2; i++)
        printf("#");

    printf("\n");

    for( i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            if( j == 0 )
                printf("#");

            printf(" ");

            if( j == length - 1)
                printf("#\n");
        }

    }

    for( i = 0; i < length + 2; i++)
        printf("#");
}
```

In case you want to display a character "*" in position (x, y), you just need to change:

```
    printf(" ");
```

by:

```
if (y == i && x == j)
    printf("*");
else
    printf(" ");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly! Funny how it was such a little problem(: Appreciate it!